# MS Access: Count Number of Zero-Records

Tags: sql, ms-access, count

I'm working with a data set that looks similar to the following:

```
  Name        Value
 Unit 1         0
 Unit 1         27
 Unit 1         30
 Unit 1         10
 Unit 1         4
 Unit 1         0
 Unit 2         0
 Unit 2         0
 Unit 2         29
 Unit 2         0
 Unit 3         10
```

and so on. I would like to create a query that lists the records as follows:

```
  Name      ZeroRecords
 Unit 1         2
 Unit 2         3
 Unit 3         0
```

Where I can list the number of records that are 0. I've tried using a totals row counting Value's, with a criteria of "=0" but it just turns up blank.

I'm sure this is much easier to do with SQL but I am not very familiar.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider grouping your records by the `Name` property along with a [`COUNT()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177890(v=office.12).aspx) aggregate to get the count for each group and if you filter it down to only check the `Value` columns that are zero, you could use :

```
  SELECT Name,
         COUNT(*) AS ZeroRecords
    FROM YourTable
   WHERE Value = 0
GROUP BY Name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation.  In MS Access, this looks like:

```
select name, sum(iif(value = 0, 1, 0)) as numzeros
from t
group by name;
```